# Android Virtual device too slow

Tags: android

I'm kind of new in the world of developing Android.

I installed Android studio 2.1.3 on my Dell, core i5, 8 GM memory, Windows 10 (x64 machine) HAXM is enabled and running.
I created a virtual device (Nexus 4 or Nexus s), but they work very very slow and almost not responding.

I found a workaround to work with other emulator (there it works smoothly)

I installed in other machine (Windows 7 x64, and there all works OK.

What can I do to improve the performance of the Android virtual device in Android Studio?

Comment: I also have same specs like yours. Instead I've 16 gigs. But mine also used to lag. It's the graphic card. For now, use x86 image. x64 is pathetically slow for me

Comment: genymotion emulator works faster: https://www.genymotion.com/ But it is also important of your pc specs. I had bought before 2 years the latest intel i7 chip and 8GB RAM pc, but it was slow slow slow....Now I have a quadcore I7 6th generation/16 GB RAM and this works like a charm.

Comment: x86 of Android. Not your OS

Comment: for fast development use real device

Comment: share your emulator specification........

Answer (score 0):

I've faced very similar issue in Windows 10 machine (16gb ram, i5 6th generation). I've tried multiple options in Android Studio and nothing work until I've

> install Windows Hypervisor Platform in control panel (look it up in
>   start menu)

Answer (score -1):

In general android simulator is slow, although you can try to allocate it more virtual memory in settings.

Recommended: Try using another simulator [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com)

Answer (score -1):

Your best bet would be [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/). It's way faster than Android's native virtual devices.